# Local extremum of multivariable functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Consider $C^\infty$ functions. For functions of one variable, we know that in general, at $x=c$ if the lowest order nonzero derivative is an even order say $2k$, then $f(c)$ is an extremum, depending on the sign of $f^{(2k)}(c)$. For example, if $f'(c)=f''(c)=f'''(c)=0$ and $f''''(c)>0$, then it is a minimum; if $f'(c)=f''(c)=0$, $f'''(c)\neq 0$, then it is not a local extremum.

Now for multivariable functions. We know the theory of Hessian matrix and eigenvalues. What if some of the second derivatives are zero? For example, consider $f(x,y)$ at $(a,b)$: $f_x=f_y=f_{xx}=f_{xy}=0$. Apparently if $f_{xxx}\neq 0$ the function cannot have a local extremum there, as the trend along the $x$-axis is monotone. Suppose $f_{xxxx},f_{yy}$ do not vanish. Should we examine the eigenvalues of
\begin{equation}
H=\begin{bmatrix} f_{xxxx} & f_{xxy}\\ f_{xxy} & f_{yy}\end{bmatrix}?
\end{equation}
What is the general theory about it? Any reference on this? thanks!

Comment: The following reference is about this question. Maybe it is of some help: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/265638239_Extrema_in_Case_of_Several_Variables

Comment: @Gerd Thanks. The necessary and sufficient conditions seem obvious. An example is $f(x,y)=x^2\pm y^4$. Suppose $f(x,y)$ has a minimum at $(0,0)$, and the $2k$-th (lowest)$x$ partial derivative is nonzero there. Does there exist $\epsilon>0$ such that $f(x,y)>\epsilon x^{2k}$ near $(0,0)$?

Comment: I think in this form it does not hold. Isn't $f(x,y)=(x-y)^4$ a counterexample?

Comment: No, $(x-y)^4$ does not have a minimum at $(0,0)$. I assume $f(x,y)>f(0,0)$ near it.